# Is there a better way to prepopulate fields?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to create an edit form with the database values pre-populated in the front end. Right now I have lots of literal controls that act like placeholders and I assign the values for those on page load.

Is there a better way to do this? Or, is this the standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use databinding on the actual form fields.  The syntax will vary depending on what your data source is, but in general it's something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="LastName" runat="server" 
   Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(MyDataSource.LastName) %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Can a datasource be a backend property like a string, or a collection?

Comment: @chobo Sure.  If it's a string variable though then you can just use `Text='<%=someStringVariable%>'`.